# What is the easiest way to show a log file in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a log file, in a memorystream, that can easily be read to a string. But I am not sure how i display this file best in WPF. I tried a TextBlock and binded it to the text property. But the application just dies when loading the file.

Are there other controls that will be good to show a log file within. There are no parameters, its just one record pr line of text that i would like to show and easy scroll within.

Every now and then a new line is added to the log and i need to update the view.

## Solution

Using AvalonEdit , TextEditor loads fast and works nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make a `ListView` with the `ItemsSource` a list of the Records you have in your logfile.
When you use an `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource`, then you can easily update your view by adding the new record to the `ObservableCollection`.

Edit:
With 100000 records this way will take some time to initialize due to creating a `TextBlock`per record.
You could try the `TextBox` control. Maybe this will work for your case. Binding the Text Property and add the new records to the bound string.

Or maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) helps you.

Comment: I just tried that, after the property get set it just dies waiting for the records to get updated. Any way to let it know it only have to update the visual part of the list?

Comment: All you have to do is add the new string to the `ObservableCollection` and it will be displayed.  Where Exactly does it break?

Comment: There are 100000 lines in the log. It frezzes when the collection get bound. I tried adding one line at a time and adding a 1ms delay to let it update. This works but takes to long to populate the view.

Comment: Do you really want to see 1000000 lines in your interface?

Comment: No i dont and thats properly where it goes wrong. I have been searching for Data Virtualization and didnt find anything good. But it might be that the window was inside a scrollviewer and therefor everything got rendered. I have turned to AvelonEdit, which works nice.